# How to read external config file when starting a bundle jboss fuse karaf

Tags: jboss, osgi, bundle, karaf

The problem is simple: i want to print all topics from apache kafka after installing kafka module on karaf. I need to get properties from cfg file which is located in jbossfuse/etc and create a KafkaConsumer object. I want to implement BundleActivator to be able to start method in the moment of installation module. 
The question is: how can i get properties from the config file? 
I found some solution here: [some solution](http://forum.spring.io/forum/attic/spring-dynamic-modules/80682-how-to-read-external-config-file-when-starting-a-bundle), they said "  you can use ConfigAdimn service from OSGi spec. ". How can i use it? All examples with the code are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Karaf uses Felix-FileInstall to read config files: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-file-install.html
So if there is a file named kafka.cfg, it will pick it up and register a config with the ConfigAdmin-Service under the pid 'kafka'.
You can fetch the ConfigAdmin-Service and fetch the config using an Activator and read that config from there, but I strongly recommend to use DeclarativeServices or Blueprint instead to interact with the OSGi-Framework, both support injection of configuration if it is available.
Because otherwise you have to deal yourself with the following topics:

- there is no ConfigAdmin (yet), maybe because your bundle starts earlier)
- the ConfigAdmin changes (for example due to a package refresh or update)
- the configuration is not yet registered (because felix has not read it yet)
- the configuration gets updated (for example somone changes the file)